# How can function be defined via "fn" member in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, function

I found the following definition

```
$.fn.flex = function ( options ) {
   var p = this.data("flex"),
           opts = options || {};
   if (p) return p;
   this.each(function () {
      p = new Flex( this, opts );
      $(this).data("flex", p);
   });
   return opts.api ? p : this;
};
```

which defines function `flex()` in original code.

Unfortunately, it stops defining this function in my environment, i.e. function call causes an error that `flex` is not a function.

What is critical here for `flex` being a function?

**UPDATE**

Sorry, actually I didn't modify anything. I just put this javascript https://github.com/jasonenglish/jquery-flex/ into my environment (Liferay) and the code to run script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $(".flex").flex();
    });
    </script>
```

caused an error. So I replaced `$` to `jQuery` everywhere as I did before and it is still not working.

**UPDATE 2**

Hmmm. Error occurs in widget.js from Twitter. Says

```
TypeError: jQuery(...).flex is not a function
```

If I rename flex to flex1 everywhere, it says "flex1" is not a function.

Comment: @Dims, can you post your modified version?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, if anything is not defined, it becomes global object. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @AmitJoki: A global *variable* (not necessarily referring to an object), yes, unless you're using strict mode which makes it the error it should be.

Comment: I've fixed the **seriously** misleading indentation in your code snippet. `opts` *is* being declared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Sorry, actually I didn't modify anything. I just put this javascript ... into my environment (Liferay) and the code to run script

Because that's a jQuery plug-in, you need to make sure you include that script *after* jQuery on the page. So

```
<script src="/path/to/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/path/to/the-plugin.js"></script>
```

If you put them in the other order, the first script will fail because it will try to take the value of the `jQuery` symbol, which doesn't exist yet, throwing a `ReferenceError` (in both loose and strict mode).

Comment: @Dims: Then either the plug-in's code isn't running, or jQuery is getting loaded a second time, later. If you load jQuery twice, the second copy overwrites the first, and any plugins that were registered with the first are no longer registered (since the copy they were registered with is gone).

Answer (score 2):

First of all in `$.fn.flex`  `$` and `fn` are jQuery variables. they are not native to JavaScript. `$.fn` provided by jQuery to attach method/property to jquery object

Comment: Are you sure? The function starts with `;(function ( $, undefined ) {  "use strict";...`. Doesn't this make `$` a local variable?

Comment: @Dims it depends what is passed in as first parameter to this function

Comment: @Dims: `$` is an argument (*effectively* a local variable). At the end of the plugin's code, you'll see that it passes in `jQuery` as that argument. This is a fairly standard idiom for plugins, which are not supposed to rely on the global `$` symbol, just the global `jQuery` symbol.